# Reference to Thrift not found when running nodejs Thrift example

Tags: javascript, node.js, thrift, thrift-protocol

I am trying to run the nodejs server/client thrift example but I cannot get it to run. Initially, I added thrift as a dependency in my `package.json` file. Then I did an `npm install` which installed thrift. Then I attempted to run the server using `node NodeServer.js`. I get a similar error when I try to run `NodeClient.js`.

Link to the Thrift nodejs tutorial - http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/nodejs

I have attached the output from the relevant commands below.

```
h@h-vbox:~/git/nodejs-thrift$ ls
gen-js  NodeClient.js  NodeServer.js  package.json  shared.thrift  tutorial.thrift
h@h-vbox:~/git/nodejs-thrift$ npm install

> ws@0.4.32 install /home/h/git/nodejs-thrift/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory '/home/h/git/nodejs-thrift/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
bufferutil.target.mk:92: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o' failed
make: Leaving directory '/home/h/git/nodejs-thrift/node_modules/ws/build'
nodethrift-server@0.0.1 /home/h/git/nodejs-thrift
└─┬ thrift@0.9.3 
  ├── node-int64@0.3.3 
  ├── q@1.0.1 
  └─┬ ws@0.4.32 
    ├── commander@2.1.0 
    ├── nan@1.0.0 
    ├── options@0.0.6 
    └── tinycolor@0.0.1 

npm WARN nodethrift-server@0.0.1 No description
npm WARN nodethrift-server@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN nodethrift-server@0.0.1 No license field.
h@h-vbox:~/git/nodejs-thrift$ node NodeServer.js 
/home/h/git/nodejs-thrift/gen-js/Calculator.js:384
Thrift.inherits(CalculatorClient, SharedServiceClient)
^

ReferenceError: Thrift is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/h/git/nodejs-thrift/gen-js/Calculator.js:384:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/h/git/nodejs-thrift/NodeServer.js:21:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
h@h-vbox:~/git/nodejs-thrift$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, I was making a mistake by generating my thrift files using the `js` flag instad of the `js:node` flag. The correct way to generate these files is,

```
thrift -r --gen js:node tutorial.thrift
```